# ios swift models structure with realm database

Tags: ios, realm, swift4, xcode9, pojo

I am developing my iOs App and I am using Realm database. As I am totally new to ios developing (also swift and xcode) I have question about structuring data (I've already read some general project structure guidelines but couldn't find the answer). My thinking is connected with Java structures

For Realm databases (RealmSiwft) I created a model like this:

```
@objcMembers class Patient: Object {
    dynamic var patientId:Int = 0
    dynamic var refNumber:String = ""

    convenience init(id:Int, refNumber:String){
       self.init()
       self.patinetID = id
       self.refNumber = refNumber
    }
}
```

Now, it looks just like a POJO class in Java. But as I learned, this model structure is made that way so it can be able to use Realm.

So the question is, if I need somewhere else in my project to use Patient objects, is this Realm-POJO-model good to use? I mean, should I use it just like a normal Model even when I dont need to make database operations on it? Or should I make this Realm model alike DAO class for databases operations and make another model class like Patient.swift for whenever I want to play with Patient without using databases (I hope not, cause it's so much code duplicating)

And what if I need variables in that Patient Model that won't be stored in database? Can I make it without dynamic? What about init than? That blows my mind, as far as I learn swift it seems so ugly and unstructured, or I just can't switch to it yet...

Comment: Check updated answer, and give normal comment instead of minus. People try to help you.

Comment: well, I didn't give a minuse to anyone.. Why I got a minuse though? I don't even have enought reputation to give minuses man

Comment: It's not my too. Somebody don't like your question and my answer ;)

Comment: ehh.. for me your answer is helpfull :) btw. I tried to look for a bigger example projects in swift with a proper files structure (with models, etc etc) like in e.x. java projects) and couldn't find good one.. All examples I found are chaotic and so unclean.. Is swift a language of type "When you need it in a class than make it even if its duplicated code"?

Comment: Check this tutorial: [raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/112544/realm-tutorial-getting-started) , [appcoda](https://www.appcoda.com/realm-database-swift/), [off doc](https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/). All other info I have searched in web and trid different possible variants and solution in pet projects.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check those out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I need somewhere else in my project to use Patient objects, is this
>   Realm-POJO-model good to use?
>   even when I dont need to make database operations on it?

You can use your Patient object without savings to the DB, move them to different controllers and so on.

> what if I need variables in that Patient Model that won't be stored
>   in database?

Look to `ignoredProperties()` method.

> Can I make it without dynamic?

No you can't because of Realm based on Objective-C object, so this is necessary type.

> What about init than?

You can create different Constructors methods, look to the [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) doc. In case with Realm you should setup values to noticed variables (if you don't give them Default Property Values)

Your class should look like this:

```
class Patient: Object {

    // MARK: - Properties
    @objc dynamic var patientId: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var refNumber: String = ""

    // MARK: - Meta
    // to set the model’s primary key
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "patientId"
    }

    //Ignoring properties
    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
       return ["tmpID"]
    }

    //It's ok
    convenience init(id:Int, refNumber:String){
        self.init()
        self.patientId = id
        self.refNumber = refNumber
    }
}
```

All other detail information you can find in: [realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)

Also you can extend you base code with swift extension:

```
extension Patient {
    var info: String {
        return "\(patientId) " + refNumber
    }

    func isAvailableRefNumber() -> Bool {
        return refNumber.length > 6
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About that minuse - that wasn't me